# Animation for converting Circular image to Rounded corner in android

Tags: android

I have an image with circular shape,I want to apply an animation for Circular image,so that it should slowly convert into little bigger size rounded corner image.
 I tried for converting circular image to rounded corner but could not able to write an animation like effect.

This makes me to convert image into rounded rectangle,but I wants the Animation for this 
kind of performance.My animation should slowly convert my circular image to rectangle with rounded corners and also increase in size

```
public  Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels)
    {
        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(result);

        color = 0xff424242;
        paint = new Paint();
        rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        rectF = new RectF(rect);
        roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: whatever you have tried.post your code.